# How to get the frequently used contacts in IOS?

Tags: ios, contacts

What I'm trying to achieve is, I want to get the list of contacts which are frequently used in IOS, but I don't know how to do this and couldn't find any way to get this done. Right now, I'm fetching all of the contacts using the below code:

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate( );
CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople( addressBook );
CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount( addressBook );

for ( int i = 0; i < nPeople; i++ )
{
    ABRecordRef ref = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex( allPeople, i );
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, **no**. There is currently *(as of iOS 10)* no way in the Contacts API of retrieving most frequently used contacts.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :-) It saved my time.